# Download File from s3 using Boto via proxy server

Tags: amazon-s3, flask, boto

I have a file to this address:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/sdile_pr_2_1_1/pr/0/2/1/1/dile_0_2_1_1.nc

in a s3 bucket, that i want to make accessible via a flask app.

to do so i created a function that looks like this:

```
@app.route('/select/dile')
def select_dile_by_uri():

    uri=request.args.get('uri')

    if uri is not None:
        if uri.startswith("http://s3.amazonaws.com/"):
            path        = uri.replace("http://s3.amazonaws.com/","")
            bname, kstr = path.split("/",1) # split the bname from the key string
            conn        = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

            try:     
                bucket  = conn.get_bucket(bname)
            except:
                print "BUCKET NOT FOUND"
                return str("ERROR: bucket "+bname+" not found")
            else:
                print "BUCKET CONNECTED"
                try:
                    key = bucket.get_key(kstr)
                    print "KEY: ", key
                except:
                    print "KEY NOT FOUND"
                    return str("ERROR: key "+kstr+"not found")
                else:
                    try: 
                        key.open_read()                         # opens the file
                        headers = dict(key.resp.getheaders())   # request the headers
                        return Response(key, headers=headers)   # return a response                                  
                    except S3ResponseError as e:
                        return Response(e.body, status=e.status, headers=key.resp.getheaders()) 



    abort(400)
```

the download works, but the name of the downloaded file appears to be only "dile" instead of dile_0_2_1_1.nc .

How come ? is there something i needed to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i needed to do was add a field into the headers, specifically:

```
headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline; filename=myfilename"
```

where -myfilename- is the name you want the file to have.